# what does *The range of k that the number of real solutions is maximum* mean in this context?

Tags: functions

> For a constant $k$, we consider the number of distinct real solutions of equation $x|x^2-3x+2|=k$. **The range of k that the number of real solutions is maximum** is $? < k < ?$, and the maximum number of real solutions is $?$

This exercise is not particularly difficult, but i'm struggling with interpretation for the question above, you see, this is how i approach it:

$$
x|x^2-3x+2| = k \quad \therefore \quad (x-1)(x-2) = \frac kx \cup (x-1)(x-2) = -\frac kx
$$

So as you can see, we are gonna end up with 4 equations which i did like this:

$ b^2-4ac \geq 0$ Use the discrimant formula for each of the equations below

$(i) x^2-x-k=0 \therefore 1+4 \geq 0 \therefore 5 \geq 0 \quad \text{ has 2 solutions }$

$(ii) x^2-2x-k=0 \therefore 4+4 \geq 0 \therefore 8 \geq 0 \quad \text{ has 2 solutions }$

$(iii) x^2-x+k=0 \therefore 1-4 \geq 0 \therefore -3 \ngeq 0 \quad \text{ no real solutions }$

$(iiii) x^2-2x+k=0 \therefore 4-4 \geq 0 \therefore 0 \geq 0 \quad \text{ has only 1 real solution }$

> the maximum number of real solutions is $?$

$2+2+0+1=5$.

But for the other part i'm kinda confused about the meaning of the question, what does **The range of $k$ that the number of real solutions is maximum** mean?, does it mean to plug $5$ into the equation? I don't think so, please help me clarify this.

Comment: *"So as you can see, we are gonna end up with 4 equations which i did like this:"* <-- Which four equations? Could you please state those four equations? I suspect you're doing something wrong there.

Comment: @zipirovich please check again, i've post the equations i refer.

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what I thought. Sorry, but this is completely wrong. From the equation $(x-1)(x-2)=\frac{k}{x}$ you "deduced" that either $x-1=\frac{k}{x}$ or $x-=\frac{k}{x}$, and the same for the other one, and that's where your four equations came from. Sorry again, but you need to work on your understanding of elementary arithmetic, and of the multiplication of numbers in particular. Your deduction is that "$A\cdot B=C$ implies either $A=C$ or $B=C$" is completely wrong. There's only one special number $C$ for which it works.

Comment: (continued) For example, let's say $(x-1)(x-2)=10$. (In the notation of the comment above, that's $A=(x-1)$, $B=(x-2)$, and $C=10$.) Does it mean that either $x-1=10$ or $x-2=10$? In other words, is that true that as long as one number is $10$ its product with any other number is equal to $10$ regardless of what that other number is? Let's try: if $x-1=10$, then $x=11$; but plugging into the original equation yields $(x-1)(x-2)=(11-1)(11-2)=10\cdot9=\ldots?$, not $10$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint. First, plot the graph of $y=x|x^2-3x+2|$ (which you can do with technology, but you should also be able to do this by hand by opening up the absolute value as a piecewise function). Then, while looking at that graph, imagine all possible horizontal lines $y=k$ (or actually draw a bunch of typical ones). The number of solutions to the equation $x|x^2-3x+2|=k$ is the number of intersection points of the two. Indeed, you will see that the maximum number of intersection points is $5$ (although I'm afraid you accidentally came to the same conclusion by luck, as your reasoning doesn't look quite right). Moreover, you will see which horizontal lines $y=k$ intersect that graph five times rather than fewer times — and that will be the desired range for $k$.

Comment: I know that the answer is 5 'cause i got the answer sheet, i think that's a good reasoning but i could be wrong, however, this exercise is not designed for the student to draw a graph, that could be time consuming, therefore, the answer is the meaning of **The range of k that the number of real solutions is maximum** which could not be other thing than a condition, but i don't quite get how that it's suppose to be see in mathematical form.

Comment: @Carlos: How do you know that "the exercise is not designed for students to draw a graph"? Why not use graphing if it helps?

Comment: This test is from japan diplomatic mission for the japanese mext scholarship, this particular question comes from past 2019 examination, each test are supposed to be done under a time of 60 minutes, so you could say that graphing could be a pain in this kind of situation, if you wanna see more details [here is the test](https://www.studyinjapan.go.jp/ja/_mt/2021/06/2019_ga_math_a.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

***Now I don't have the enough time to write it, but I will do later. Here's what I did to solve it (It has to exists a faster way to do it). First find the zeros of the absolute value $x^2-3x+2=0 \iff x=2,1$. After that, write $f(x)$ as follows.
$$
\begin{gathered}
f(x)= \begin{cases}
x^3-3x^2+2x & x\geq 2 \lor x\leq1 \\
-x^3+3x^2-2x & 1<x<2\\
\end{cases}
\end{gathered}
$$
Now find its derivative $f'(x)$.
$$
\begin{gathered}
f'(x)= \begin{cases}
3x^2-6x+2 & x> 2 \lor x<1 \\
-3x^2+6x-2 & 1<x<2 \\
\end{cases}
\end{gathered}
$$
Now impose $f'(x)=0$ and you will get 2 values for the first part and two values for the other. For the second part, one of the values is <1, then it won't count. Find their images and then you will get its maximums and minimums. For the number of solutions, you can use its monotony and the definition of $x^3$ in order to get that "they have to cut" 5 times.